# Cronned Django command output not posted in tee from bash script

Tags: django, bash, cron, tail, tee

I'm trying to have a bash script that controled by `cron` to be ran every day and I would like to grep some lines from the `python` (Django) output and post it with [slacktee](https://github.com/course-hero/slacktee) to my slack channel. But I am only catching some warnings from the script, not my own prints (something to do with std::out and std::err)? But I can't seem to be able to debug it.

```
#!/bin/bash

printf "\nStarting the products update command\n"
DATE=`date +%Y-%m-%d`
source mypath/bin/activate

cd some/path/_production/_server

./manage.py nn_products_update > logs/product_updates.log

tail --lines=1000 logs/product_updates.log | grep INFO | grep $DATE
```

So for each day, I'm trying to grep messages like these:

```
[INFO][NEURAL_RECO_UPDATE][2017-08-28 22:15:04] Products update...
```

But it doesn't get printed in the tee channel. Moreover, the file gets overwritten everyday and not appended - how to change that, please? The `tail` command works ok when ran in the shell by itself. How is it possible? (sorry for asking two, but I believe they are somehow related, just cant find an answer)

This is just in case the `cron` entry.

```
20 20 * * * /bin/bash /path/to/server/_production/bin/runReco.sh 2>&1 | slacktee.sh -c 'my_watch'
```

Many thanks

**EDIT:**

output when using `grep -e INFO -e $DATE`

```
grep: [INFO][NEURAL_RECO_UPDATE][2017-08-29: No such file or directory
grep: 07:36:56]: No such file or directory
grep: No: No such file or directory
grep: new: No such file or directory
grep: active: No such file or directory
grep: products: No such file or directory
grep: to: No such file or directory
grep: calculate.: No such file or directory
grep: Terminating...: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -euo pipefile
```

this will provide better debug output from your script
See [bash strict mode article](http://redsymbol.net/articles/unofficial-bash-strict-mode/) for a full explanation of the settings.

The file gets overwritten because you are using a single > (redirection) rather than >> which appends redirected output.

To help debug further it would probably make life easier if you put

> 2>&1 | slacktee.sh -c 'my_watch'

In your runReco.sh as in:

```
tail --lines=1000 logs/product_updates.log | grep INFO | grep $DATE 2>&1 | slacktee.sh -c 'my_watch'
```

Although chaining lots of commands together in shell scripts makes them harder to debug.

Hence breaking up the tail line:

```
TMPFILE=`tail --lines=1000 logs/product_updates.log`
grep -e INFO -e $DATE $TMPFILE 2>&1 | slacktee.sh -c 'my_watch'
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer. It sort of works, but when I use the TMPFILE and grep -e as you suggest, if prints stuff like what I edited in my question above.  Mostly, the problem was in the `>` vs `>>` and now it works, but the grep by `DATE` doesnt work, the whole file with `INFO` in it gets printed. :(

Comment: does: `grep -e INFO -e $DATE  logs/product_updates.log` generate the right output?  the `--line-buffered` option to grep will probably be needed on the output in `$TMPFILE`

Comment: It got fixed simply with the `>>` now it works great! Thanks a lot!